# Cannot simplify or reduce a region

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

I have a region specified by a rather short expression, and the same region by a longer one, and cannot
seem to reduce the size of the longer one. A simple example is

```
con1 = Simplify[x + z >= 0 && x <= 1 && x >= 0 && 0 >= z]
con2 = Simplify[(z == 0 && 
     0 <= x <= 1) || (x == 1 && -1 <= z < 0) || (-1 < z < 0 && 
     x + z >= 0 && x < 1)]
Reduce[con1 && ! con2]
Reduce[con2 && ! con1]
```

The last two statements assure that they are the same region by returning False in both cases.

This is a simplified version with y=0 of my real problem in x, y, and z, in which I cannot shorten the con2 expression.

```
con1 = Simplify[
  y >= 0 && x >= -z && x <= 1 - 2 y && x >= 0 && y >= z/4]
con2 = Simplify[(z == 0 && y == 0 && x == 0) || (z == 2 && y == 1/2 &&
      x == 0) || (1 <= z < 2 && y == 1/2 && x == 0) || (0 <= z < 1 && 
     y == 1/2 && 
     x == 0) || (((z == 0 && 0 < x < 1) || (0 < z < 1 && 
         0 <= x < 1 - z)) && 
     y == z/4) || (((z == 0 && x == 1) || (0 < z <= 1 && 
         1 - z <= x <= (2 - z)/2) || (1 < z < 2 && 
         0 <= x <= (2 - z)/2)) && y == z/4) || (y == 0 && 
     x == 1 && -1 <= z < 0) || (0 < y <= 1/4 && 
     1 - 4 y <= x <= 1 - 2 y && -1 + 4 y <= z < 4 y) || (1/4 < y < 1/
      2 && 0 <= x <= 1 - 2 y && -1 + 4 y <= z < 4 y) || (0 < y <= 1/
      4 && 1 - 4 y < x <= 1 - 2 y && -x <= z < -1 + 4 y) || (1/4 < y <
       1/2 && 0 <= x <= 1 - 2 y && -x <= z < -1 + 4 y) || (-1 < z < 
      0 && 0 <= y < (1 + z)/4 && -z <= x < 1 - 4 y) || (0 <= z < 1 && 
     z/4 < y < 1/4 && 0 <= x < 1 - 4 y)]
Reduce[con1 && ! con2]
Reduce[con2 && ! con1]
```

Comment: `CylindricalDecomposition` might be useful

Comment: `Reduce[con1 && Reduce[! Reduce[con2, Reals], Reals]]`   and `Reduce[con2 && Reduce[! con1, Reals], Reals]`  work fine.

Comment: CylindricalDecomposition seems to work very well. It expands con1 a little, but reduces con2 to the same, much smaller expression.